# Add dollar sign to x-axis on plot

Tags: r, plot, format, visualization, data-manipulation

I made this plot

```
data(iris)
plot(density(iris$Sepal.Length), xlab = "xlab")
```

[image]

I know this is non-sensical, but would there have been a way to add a "dollar sign" to each unit on the x-axis? For example:

[image]

I tried to this the following way:

```
library(priceR)
iris$Sepal.Length = format_dollars(iris$Sepal.Length)
plot(density(iris$Sepal.Length), xlab = "xlab")
```

But I don't think this is the right way to do this. Is there a more general way to simply add dollar signs ($) to each unit on the x-axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redraw x-axis by `paste`ing `axTicks(1)` and `$` together.

```
plot(density(iris$Sepal.Length), xlab="xlab", xaxt='n')
axis(1, axTicks(1), labels=paste0(axTicks(1), '$'))
```

[image]